# Expand All WPF TreeView Nodes At Runtime Using WPF-MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I want to expand all TreeView Items when user sets CheckBox I was able to do it at startup of the application using style :

```
       <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                          <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                        </Style>
       </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And I was thinking if I can do some thing like this :

```
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                  <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding ExpandAllItems }"/>
              </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and in viewModel :

```
 public bool ExpandAllItems ;
```

but it didn't work. any body knows how to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` to the `CheckBox.IsChecked`. Notice, that you must use converter to convert `bool?` to `bool`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but when user collapse any node it still collapsed  even if Uncheck and Recheck the CheckBox

Do have any idea how to fix it ?